# getFragmentManager().getFragmentById(R.id.fragment) returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have made a simple app which uses an action bar and I want to detect which `Fragment` is loaded. Unfortunately the following line always returns null:

```
getFragmentManager().getFragmentById(R.id.fragment)
```

To load new `Fragment`s, I am using:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: getFragmentById ? Can you post a link to the documentation

Comment: What is the ID you set for the fragment when you do `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();`?

Comment: @blackbelt here is link to the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentById(int)

Comment: @Sufian R.id.content_frame is a target where i load fragment

Comment: It'd be better if you post your XML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the FragmentTransaction sets the fragment's ID to be `R.id.content_frame` which is the container. So `getFragmentManager().getFragmentById(R.id.content_frame)` will give you the Fragment.

Also,  it is recommended to use the support library's Fragments and appcompat-v7 (`getSupportFragmentManager()` and `android.support.v4.Fragment`, extending from appcompat's `ActionBarActivity`) because they are more maintained.

Comment: Your answer was complete. Thank you. To manage which fragment is currently loaded I am using tags.